# Is there a Small Windows install of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcreader

I am looking to find a faster alternative to ArcReader.  I think QGIS might be faster but I was wondering if there was a smaller install without all the GRASS etc for windows.  I just want to get a fast map out to my users in the field. The ability to Zoom, Pan, Identify and perhaps search for an address would be nice.

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:G0ldfish/Portable_QGIS QGIS supports offline mode

Comment: If users are on Android platforms - http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/qgis-on-an-android-phone/

Answer (score 4):

If you install QGIS via osgeo4w instead of via the binary you can select which components and applications are installed.

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/