# QGIS small install package for use in low-bandwidth settings?

Tags: qgis, installation, download

I'm a cartographer and data analyst with experience using ArcGIS and QGIS to format data and produce maps for a global public health contract.  I am working with a group of QGIS learners from Africa and India who would like to be able to map health data. I've written instructions on some basic QGIS functions and have been helping them online.  But several of them have had trouble just downloading the current installer for QGIS, which is around 300Mb in size, prohibitive to those with slow/unreliable internet connections.

I was reading another post about other ways to do more advanced installations of QGIS:
[Is there a Small Windows install of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58100/is-there-a-small-windows-install-of-qgis)

...and it appears a better way to do a smaller download/install might be through the use of the OSGeo4 installer, which lets you install only the pieces of the software you need.  My trouble is, I do not know which pieces are crucial.  (I need for the group to be able to handle really only vector data files.  The most common data types they will be working with at this point include CSV files and shapefiles. We have not gotten into any raster data analysis.)

Can anyone make any suggestions?  Which packages, at a minimum, will they need?